# Segregrate records from file using awk in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have two files (FILE_A and FILE_B). How can I get the output below using shell script?

```
  $cat FILE_A
  a
  b
  c
  d

  $cat FILE_B
  b
  c

  $cat OUTPUT
  a
  d
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Is your goal to get the list of values that only appear once across both files or to find the lines from A that do not exist, in order, in B, or the lines from A that do not exist in B in any order or .... You stand a much better chance of getting the right answer if you explain your requirements instead of giving one small, ambiguous example and asking everyone to guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this (this is not using `awk` though)

```
sort FILE_A FILE_B | uniq -u
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file is sorted.
try this:

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB) | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use grep:

```
grep -f FILE_B FILE_A -v
```